# Customize Password Validation Error message Of Password Rule Class of Laravel Fortify

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

What is the efficient way to customize validation message defined in Password Rule class of Laravel Fortify ?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I am customizing messages by defining the translation as:

```php
{
    "The :attribute must be at least :length characters.": ":attribute を少なくとも :length 文字の英数字に設定してください\n文字。"
}
```

Which seems to work fine, but is there any other better way to do so ?